# TextView's show the wrong text

Tags: android, textview

my problem is something I've never seen before...

I'm trying to make an android app, and I've stuck at one small bug, and this one is very tricky.

I have 20 TextViews, 10 medium size and 10 regular size, the little ones.

And somehow two of these textviews, one medium and the other is a little one, change it's text one for another. The first should show a text and the second a number. Somehow they are inverse, and I keep looking at the code, and I can't figure out why.

Some of you are thinking that is a simple thing to solve, that I've just misplace the codes, but I'll tell, I've checked over and over again, and it seens right.

```
public void showWritings(){
    TextView tv1stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1stSpentReportM);
    tv1stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[9].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv2stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2stSpentReportM);
    tv2stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[8].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv3stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3stSpentReportM);
    tv3stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[7].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv4stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4stSpentReportM);
    tv4stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[6].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv5stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5stSpentReportM);
    tv5stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[5].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv6stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv6stSpentReportM);
    tv6stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[4].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv7stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv7stSpentReportM);
    tv7stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[3].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv8stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv8stSpentReportM);
    tv8stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[2].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv9stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv9stSpentReportM);
    tv9stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[1].getTipoGasto());

    TextView tv10stSpentReportM = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv10stSpentReportM);
    tv10stSpentReportM.setText(vetorGastos[0].getTipoGasto());


    TextView tv1stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1stSpentReportV);
    tv1stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[9].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv2stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2stSpentReportV);
    tv2stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[8].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv3stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv3stSpentReportV);
    tv3stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[7].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv4stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv4stSpentReportV);
    tv4stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[6].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv5stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv5stSpentReportV);
    tv5stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[5].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv6stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv6stSpentReportV);
    tv6stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[4].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv7stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv7stSpentReportV);
    tv7stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[3].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv8stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv8stSpentReportV);
    tv8stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[2].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv9stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv9stSpentReportV);
    tv9stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[1].getValorGasto()));

    TextView tv10stSpentReportV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv10stSpentReportV);
    tv10stSpentReportV.setText(String.valueOf(vetorGastos[0].getValorGasto()));

        }

}
```

the Medium TextViews has a M in their names, and the little ones has a V.
In the variable and in the id.

The tv2stSpentReportM is showing the text of tv2stSpentReportV and tv2stSpentReportV the text of tv2stSpentReportV.

To make things more clear, here is the code of my "Gastos.class", This one is what I have in the array vetorGastos[].

```
public class Gastos {


private String tipoGasto;

private double valorGasto;

public String getTipoGasto() {
    return tipoGasto;
}

public void setTipoGasto(String tipoGasto) {
    this.tipoGasto = tipoGasto;
}

public double getValorGasto() {
    return valorGasto;
}

public void setValorGasto(double valorGasto) {
    this.valorGasto = valorGasto;
}
```

}

[image]
As I've told you before, and no one believe me, here as printscreen showing you exacly what I've told. The id's are correct. So what now? And disbelievers, thank you for removing reputation points just cause you don't believe. Expand the Image so you could see that the id's are correct.

I already solve this one now, just rewrite ONE of the id's, and it get right. So if it was just a misplaced id, i should rewrite two id's. I don't know why. but it solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't have the ids switched around in the layout xml?

Comment: post your layout please

Comment: Given the typos in your question, and I mean this sincerely, have you taken as much care in your code?  `and tv2stSpentReportV the text of tv2stSpentReportV`

Comment: Take a few hours of rest, then look again at your code and you will probably find the error. This is obviously a "typo" in java/xml code.

Comment: I suppose you know what 2 `TextView`s that changes text, so remove the rest of the code for brevity and then post your XML layout file. Also try to rerun the code without the other `TextView`s and see if the problem persists.
Also how does your array of `Gastos` look like?

Comment: Yes!
I'm sure the id's are correct, and I miss the typing up there. cause they are too similar so I made mistake HERE, but not in the code.
I'm not at home right now, so when I get home I'll get the pictures to show you guys.
In the xml the id's are the same as the variables you can see here: tv2stSpentReportM and tv2stSpentReportV.
Cause this way I could know better who is who, one is M and the other V.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've already solve this one now.
I don't know why, but just rewrite ONE of the id's solved the problem.
If it were a misplaced id, I should change two ID's not rewrite one, the same writing.